# SQL "Where" Statement Only working for on Database Column

Tags: php, sql

My Statement works fine until I add "Where" then it just stops. I am using the same "Where" statement I used for my date column which worked fine. So I am a little baffled to way it will not work with any other column in my database. I have tried other suggestions provided in other questions regarding "Where" statements but nothing is working. Any help would be appropriated.

```
     // Create connection
     $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

$sql = "SELECT website, url, dropdown, description FROM basic
WHERE dropdown = Social Media";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 echo "<table><tr><th>Website</th><th>URL</th><th>Dropdown</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
 // output data of each row

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td><a href='".$row["website"]."'>".$row["url"]."</a></td>   
 <td>
     <td>" . $row["dropdown"]. "</td><td>" . $row["description"]. "</td>
     </tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
 } else {
 echo "0 results";
  }

 $conn->close();
  ?>
```

Comment: Add some quotes: `Where dropdown = 'Social Media'`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thank you. It is always the little things you over look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add single quotes to Social Media. Here is the line fixed:

```
$sql = "SELECT website, url, dropdown, description FROM basic
WHERE dropdown = Social 'Media'";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap "Social Media" with quotation marks, so your query should  look like this

```
SELECT website, url, dropdown, description FROM basic
Where dropdown = 'Social Media'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT website, url, dropdown, description FROM basic where dropdown = 'Social Media'";
```

Add single quotes